# Select all columns grouping by version - Postgres

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, knex.js

I need to query all columns in a table of all customers, the main factor being the latest version for each customer.

My table:

[image]

My Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(code)
    code,
    namefile,
    versioncol,
    status
FROM table_A
    ORDER BY versioncol desc
```

Error:

> ERROR: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
>   LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT ON(code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres' error message is trying to tell you what to do:

> `DISTINCT ON` expressions must match initial `ORDER BY` expressions

Actually that's quite clear: to make your code a valid `DISTINCT ON` query, you just need to add `code` (that's the *`DISTINCT ON` expression*) as a first sorting criteria to the query (ie as *initial `ORDER BY`*).

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(code) a.*
FROM table_A a
ORDER BY code, versioncol DESC
```

Comment: How can I build this query in the syntax of the knex?